# Simulate or Calculate Inductor Flyback Voltage from Component Parameters?

Tags: oscillator, capacitance, inductance, flyback, electro-mechanical

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCi9Bg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Top circuit can be used to simulate the increase in velocity of the JATO Powered Chevy featured in the first episode (and subsequent episodes) of Mythbusters. A current source represents the thrust from a JATO rocket. A capacitor represents the mass of a Chevy. The rise in voltage across the capacitor over time represents the increase in velocity of the Chevy when accelerated by the thrust from the Jato rocket. This is similar to solving for velocity using an impulse-momentum integral (force times time equals mass times change in velocity).

Can the bottom circuit can be used to coherently simulate and intuitively grasp the flyback voltage on an inductor? In electrical circuits we do not consider the analog quantity for mechanical acceleration. Flyback voltage seems to be similar to the mechanical analog wherein a small mass is driven by a large force such that the large acceleration produces a rapid change in velocity. Intuitively when switch SW2 is closed the voltage across inductor L1 and its self-capacitance C2 is zero. When switch SW2 opens the inductor changes from a power sink to a power source driving current into C2 much like the source I1 drives current into C1. Because C2 is typically very small the flyback voltage is characteristically large. I would like to quantify some realistic values and begin to simulate flyback voltage so the calculations become more accurate and intuitive.

Also I used an LC circuit with a time dependent switch between L and C to simulate the velocity of an arrow shot from a bow where the force of the bow and velocity of the arrow is generated as a frictionless horizontal linear spring-mass system. I made the switch open at 1/4 the LC oscillation period to simulate the release of the arrow with pretty good results using data generated by Mythbusters' measurements. I estimated values and allowed for fudge factors since I don't know the exact physical model for an arrow released from a stretched bow.

In the system generating the flyback inductor voltage, the self-capacitance and surrounding capacitance is always coupled to the inductor, so I am not sure how to model the system in more accurate terms. This should be similar to a spring-mass system with high force spring and small mass and some dissipation (dashpot) element that eventually damps the oscillations.

Answer (score 1):

> *Can the bottom circuit can be used to coherently simulate and
> intuitively grasp the flyback voltage on an inductor?*

**Short answer**: yes it can (by recognizing that the capacitor receives the full energy stored from the inductor some "short" time after the switch open circuits and removes the current source.

**Disclaimer**: I know nothing about "chevy" or "Jato" or "Mythbusters" and see those terms as irrelevant to the above question listed at the top of this answer.

**Longer answer**: Calculate the energy stored in the inductor at the time the switch opens: -

$$E = \frac{1}{2} L\cdot I^2$$

Apply that energy into the equation for energy stored by a capacitor: -

$$E = \frac{1}{2} C\cdot V^2$$

Numerically solve for voltage, V.

Comment: I agree with the basic answer. Self-capacitance and parasitic capacitance are very rough estimates. I suppose the energy analysis can be used to select the flyback diode. The Mythbusters television show Episode 1, January 23, 2003, ```Investigating urban legends, including whether a 1967 Chevy can be turned into a 350 mph road machine```. To simulate top speed assume the Chevy weighs 3500 pounds and goes 140 MPH initial velocity. JATO rocket (Jet Assist Take-Off) fires with maximum thrust and time. Apply force-current analog. To simulate impulse-momentum use SI units in transient ckt analysis.

Comment: @SystemTheory if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

**Inductors Application Notes (4 page pdf)**

https://www.murata-ps.com/pub/data/apnotes/mpan-01.pdf

Figure 6 on page 3 shows a Spice equivalent inductor circuit with an inductor, capacitor, and two resistors.

[image]

In the simplified analysis below the series resistor is a short circuit and the parallel resistor is an open circuit. The result is an ideal inductor in parallel with its self-capacitance.

Page 4 shows data sheet values for an inductor. Values are inserted into the Solver model below to find the estimated flyback voltage. The values for I0, L, and Cs produce a flyback voltage 5,430 volts that reaches a peak in about 0.07 microseconds.

[image]